# Does not work OnItemClick when I use two Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

Hello I have two activities with ListViews, I can call second activity from first but when I close second activity and return to first activity, OnItemClick doesn't work, So you know where is problem and how to solve it?

first activity onCreate

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_words_activity);
    list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.add_words_list);
    getClassData();
    wordItems=new ArrayList<WordItem>();
    adapter=new AddWordsAdapter(this, wordItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);

    list.setOnTouchListener(listViewTouchListener);

}
```

first activity ItemClick

```
          private OnItemClickListener itemClick=new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        isEditWordDilaog=true;
        start=words.get(position);
        Log.d(start.getWord(),"what the fuck");
        end=new WordData();
        final int langId=start.getLanguageId();
        end.setLanguageId(langId);
        showDialog(WORD_DIALOG);
        wordViewHolder.language.setImageResource(RProvider.
                getLangImageId(languages.get(langId)));
        wordViewHolder.word.setText(start.getWord());
        wordIndex=position;

    }

};
```

first activity on touch:

```
 private OnTouchListener listViewTouchListener =new OnTouchListener() {
    float startX,endX;
    boolean isMove=false;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int action=event.getAction();
        switch(action){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX=event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            isMove=true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            endX=event.getX();
            if(isMove==true && startX<endX){
                Rect rect=new Rect();           
                int endY=(int)event.getY();
                for(int i=0;i<list.getChildCount();i++){
                    View child=list.getChildAt(i);
                    int left=child.getLeft();
                    int right=child.getRight();
                    int bottom=child.getBottom();
                    int top=child.getTop();
                    rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
                    if(rect.contains((int)endX,endY)){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(AddWordsActivity.this,AddTranslateActivity.class);
                        int id=words.get(i).getId();
                        intent.putExtra(Names.WORD_ID,id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            /*
            endX=event.getX();
            if(startX<endX){
                isMove=true;

            }*/
            break;

        }
        isLongClick=!isMove;
        return isMove;
    }
};
```

In second activity I use back button for close it. after than itemClick doesn't not work

Comment: Post your code so we can have a look.

Comment: Indeed you should really post some code here so we can find the error for you or at least help you find it. If not this question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `OnTouchListener`. Unless it is doing something other than starting the `Intent`. It would seem that your `OnClickListener` is only setting some variables and isn't the method starting the `Intent`. From the Android Developer documentation:

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Added in API level 1
Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters
parent      The AdapterView where the click happened.
view        The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
position    The position of the view in the adapter.
id          The row id of the item that was clicked.
```

I would remove the `OnTouchListener` and place this inside the `OnClickListener`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddWordsActivity.this,AddTranslateActivity.class);
int id = words.get(position).getId();
intent.putExtra(Names.WORD_ID,id);
startActivity(intent);
```

You may be able to replace the entire `int id` variable with the `id` given by the `OnClickListener` but without knowing what your `words` variable is, I can't tell you for sure.

Adding the `Intent` declaration to your `OnClickListener` means that every time the item is clicked, it will start the `Intent`. From there, you add your extras and you're done.

Good luck, and I hope this helped.